# Como mostrar a mensagem de erro enviada pelo Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js

Tenho o seguinte método no *back-end*, que faz o login:

```
const login = async (req, resp) => {
  try {
    if (!req.body.id) throw 'Necessário Informar ID';

    const ongFromDB = await db('ongs').select('name').where({ id: req.body.id }).first();

    if (!ongFromDB) throw 'ONG não Encontrada.';

    resp.status(201).send(ongFromDB);
  } catch (error) {
    resp.status(400).send(error);
  }
};
```

E estou tentando pegar no *front-end* com React:

```
function handleLogon(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  api.post('/login', { id })
    .then(response => {
      localStorage.setItem('ongId', response.data.name);
      console.log(response.data.name);
      history.push('/profile');
    })
    .catch(e => {
      alert(e.data); // Ou alert(e)
    });
}
```

Mas não consigo pegar o texto, mesmo que no Postman consiga ver a mensagem.

Só consigo algo como:

> ```
> Error: Request failed with status code 400
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Quando o axios faz uma requisição que encontra um [*status*](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) de erro — `4xx` ou `5xx` —, um erro será lançado. Esse erro será capturado pelo método `catch`, da sua `Promise`.

Esse erro conterá um objeto `response`, que você poderá usar para obter propriedades da resposta. Consulte a [documentação dessa biblioteca](https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors) para saber mais.

Utilize `error.response.data` para obter o texto que você está enviando do *back-end*:

```js
api
  .post('/login', {})
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error.response.data);
  });
```